# How to include a blade file which has a full stop (.) as part of the file name in blade

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have a partial view with the following path.

```
/views/acp/review/check.details.blade.php
```

How do I include such a file using blade because If I do

```
@include('views.acp.review.check.details')
```

I get an error because It attempts to parse `check.details` as `check/details`

Please how can I include the file having the full stop?

**Edit: I don't want to Rename the file**

Comment: I would recommend that you change your file extension if possible. Use another special character for separate "check" and "details". This style leads to ugly and non existing file extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Blade uses the . as directory separators and you probably don't want to change that :)

Rename the file to:

```
/views/acp/review/check-details.blade.php
```

and use:

```
@include('views.acp.review.check-details')
```

Comment: Yep but in this case I don't want to rename the file. Perhaps I should just use plain PHP to include it. I taught it was possible with blade.

Comment: Not directly, blade is hardcoded to do `return str_replace('.', '/', $name).'.'.$extension;`. Only way you can change this behavior is implementing your own version of `ViewFinderInterface` and overlaoding the default `ViewServiceProvider` accordingly. It's not too hard to do that, but as said, you probably don't want to change that. I would recommend sticking to the Laravel naming convention while working on Laravel projects.