# Laravel blade path with . (Period, full stop) in the path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a json which has . (period) in the key part of the json. This is making it hard to path to in Laravel blade.

```
{
"id":138,
"desc":"testinfo",
"fields":{ "System.AreaPath":"Project 1"}
}
```

I can string the replace the . with nothing but then I am also removing them from email addresses as well.

```
{{$resp->fields->System.AreaPath}}
```

Does not work.

I've tried alternative char which blade does not support. (e.g. $ % ^ & | ,) if I replace the json string from . to XXX then i get a

```
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit what you're trying to achieve and where does blade come into picture?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is another way beside substituting the full stop. Are you sure you can't work around the e-mail problem? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41585874/how-to-include-a-blade-file-which-has-a-full-stop-as-part-of-the-file-name-i)

Comment: Of course, I'm getting the feed from a Microsoft API, so the keys and content are out of my control. I using guzzle to make the main call, and then pass the json into my Blade.

Comment: So iterate over `fields` property and change `.` in keys.

Comment: I had tried the iteration however it iterates over the keys and values each in turn. I felt a little grubby doing that. I was going to save that as a "Plan Z", thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.AreaPath` is interpreted as a variable which is not allowed in PHP. Same is the case for `$ % ^ & | , -` and other symbols too.

You can Try Array

```
$string =  '{
"id":138,
"desc":"testinfo",
"fields":{ "System.AreaPath":"Project 1"}
}'
```

then use `json_decode($string, TRUE);`

Now you can access like this.

```
{{$resp['fields']['System.AreaPath']}}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does work, can you tell me the difference between $resp->id and $resp["id"]?

Answer (score 0):

```
$resp->fields->{"System.AreaPath"}
```

Comment: No good I'm afriad, the blade looks like

{{$resp->fields->{"System.Title"}}}

And the render looks good. But it doesn't render.